# How to use asserts in callback function javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, callback, js-test-driver

I have following code in test case:

```
flickrJson.prototype.testFlickrPhotoSearch = function() {
var wrongName = "googday";
var key = "3f807259749363aaa29c76012fa93945";
flickrPhotoSearch(wrongName, key, 1, handleData);
```

}

And `handleData` function:

```
var handleData = function(photoUrl)
{
    if (photoUrl.stat)
    {
        if (photoUrl.stat === "ok")
        {
            assertEquals(1,2);

        }
    }
}
```

I want to fail this test case. But when I write assert inside `handleData` function, it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure `photoUrl.stat === "ok"` and the callback is being called?

Comment: yes we are in this condition.

Comment: I suggest using a test runner like Mocha, and reading its documentation for asynchronous tests. Otherwise, you're naturally required to make your minimal test harness (which I suppose you have) support asynchronous tests yourself.

Comment: Mocha is a different setup. Can we do this in js-test-driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this I have found the best way is to set a variable in the callback to some meaningful value (or values - perhaps one meaning ok, and another failure), then in the body of the test wait for the variable to be set (including a timeout so the test will fail if the variable is *never* set) and then once the test knows the variable is set - assert that it has the expected value.

This is not a problem specific to JavaScript or any particular unit testing library; but it is  a problem inherent in testing asynchronous code.